# Passing from Python to HTML for GAE

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

In my python for Google App Engine, I have this

```
MAIN_PAGE_FOOTER_TEMPLATE = """\
<form action="/sign?%s" method="post">
  <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
</form>
<hr>
<form>Guestbook name:
  <input value="%s" name="guestbook_name">
  <input type="submit" value="switch">
</form>
</body>
</html>"""
```

which is used in these functions

```
self.response.write('<html><body>')
self.response.write(MAIN_PAGE_FOOTER_TEMPLATE %
                        (sign_query_params, cgi.escape(guestbook_name)))
```

So I understand that the %s in the top code takes in the parameters provided at the bottom code. However, I am unsure as to how I can do this in a HTML file, rather than coding in python, as it becomes very messy if the HTML code is long. Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates

Comment: Yay thanks it works!